# Server side responsiveness good practices

Tags: cakephp, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I have the following scenario: I work with CakePHP and Twitter Bootstrap. 
I'm using a lot of responsiveness and writing lots of HTML that change for each screen size. 
I was thinking about detecting the screen size and saving it on the server side, so I can write only the HTML that will really be useful on that page. Since the user rarely changes the window size, won't hurt to hit F5.

Is it a good practice? What do you suggest?

Comment: "Since the user rarely changes the window size" - You'll find they do. And also, people rotate their tablets.

Comment: Yeah, forgot about that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That job is clearly supposed to be done by the browser and your task it to make that happen by using the right CSS for the right device. As somebody already mentioned in the comment, your device could rotate, devices have different DPI. I'm pretty sure you can't pass the DPI to the server without explicitly reading it via JS (if possible at all) and passing it to the server in an AJAX call.

You can't rely on your server side device detection alone nor is it good to render Markup conditionally for that purpose it just increases the maintenance amount you have to do by X for each device.

I recommend you to read a little more about repsonsive webdesign, there are plenty of articles and books about it these days.

Comment: I agree that the work must be done by the browser, however the code can grow a lot and there might be hundreds of uselless lines for a given device. But I realize now that this is the burden of the responsiveness.

Comment: No there are not going to be any useless lines if it's done right.

Answer (score 1):

Not really a good practice mate. You'll increase your application load and you'll waste unnecessary space just to save a few lines of code. Imagine if you're making a website like facebook, how much server space would it require to just store that piece of information for millions of users. Responsive design is a must these days in css and you should just give general values for ranges of resolutions. There's a good paid tutorial on team tree house's website i think, and others are freely available on youtube etc.